# Combining multiple diacritics in Linux Libertine

Tags: fonts, xetex, accents, font-encodings, libertine

In several Native American languages, nasal vowels are marked with an ogonek and can take an acute accent. I'm using XeLaTeX to put together a proceedings volume, and for some reason, I cannot get a lower-case  with an ogonek and an acute accent to display properly; the tittle will always appear along with the acute.

In (15), we can see the problem. One workaround I've found is to use the dotless  as a base and add the combining diacritics, like in (16), but the combining ogonek seems to stick out too far to the left and looks odd when next to another  with an ogonek.

[image]

Is there a better solution to get an  with an ogonek that simply is able to have the acute in place of the tittle, rather that have both the tittle and the acute accent appear at the same time?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,letterpaper,openright,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}

\item \glll šį́į blį́iyáu\\
    šį w-yį́=ao\\
    \textnormal{fat} 1a-\textnormal{be}=decl\\  
    \glt `I'm fat' 

\item \glll yiiškí hnáhnįao\\
    yi=škí Ø-y-ya-hnı̨́=ao\\
    2a=\textnormal{also} 3p-2a-ins-\textnormal{swallow}=decl\\
    \glt `you swallowed it, too' 

\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your setup is somewhat unclear. You mention that you use XeLaTeX, yet you load the `fontenc`, `inputenc`, and `libertine` packages. If instead of loading these three packages, you loaded the `fontspec` package and executed the instruction `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}`, your example appears to run correctly under both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Or am I missing something? Please advise.

Comment: There isn't really anything you can do.  It's a bug in the font.  If you want it fixed, you should switch from Linux Libertine to Libertinus and report the problem on the [Libertinus bugtracker](https://github.com/libertinus-fonts/libertinus/issues).

Comment: Ah, I realize now what I was missing before: the issue with the acute accent interfering with the tittle shows up if the text is typeset in italics. (The upright font face seems to be ok.) Indeed, this must be a font bug.

Comment: never do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in xelatex that forces the use of legacy tex font encoding with 256 characters, not unicode fonts, and will give incorrect hyphenation. (although in this case you are lucky that the libertine package is detecting xetex and over-ruling this)

Comment: I appreciate knowing that this is a bug with the font and not pure user error. @HenriMenke, this seems like the best solution. Thank you for pointing out that Libertinus is the active successor to Linux Libertine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to a bug in the font.